# Django Compress Creating Outdated CSS Versioned Files

Tags: django, compression

I'm using [django-compress](http://code.google.com/p/django-compress/) to minify my JS and CSS files and I've found it works great and really speeds up my site when it works.

Problem is, I've been using the [FarFutureExpires](http://code.google.com/p/django-compress/wiki/FarFutureExpires) feature to generate versioned files, but I've found in some scenarios django-compress seems to generate old file names on disk, so that my generated HTML includes references to a more recent version that what was created by the `manage.py synccompress` command.

For example:

```
./manage.py synccompress

CSS Group 'content_css'
----------------------- 
Version: 1311733749 
Removing outdated file content.min1311643450.css 
Saving min/css/content.min1311643450.css

CSS Group 'account_css'
----------------------- 
Version: 1311733749 
Removing outdated file account.min1311643450.css 
Saving min/css/account.min1311643450.css


CSS Group 'file_css'
--------------------------- 
Version: 1311733749 
Removing outdated file file.min1311643450.css 
Saving min/css/file.min1311643450.css

CSS Group 'home_css'
-------------------- 
Version: 1311733749 
Removing outdated file home.min1310605109.css 
Saving min/css/home.min1310605109.css
```

Here you can see the latest version is **1311733749**, and this is what appears in my rendered markup, but for some reason an older revision, **1310605109**, is actually created on disk. I then have to go manually mv all the filenames to the correct version in order to use get the site to load properly.

I've looked through the docs and searched online but I can't find anything - anyone know offhand why this might occur before I go to the source?